# Kerning issues with headless chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, testing, headless

Running some selenium tests that involve screenshot based assertions and running to the following issue:

[image]

For some reason headless chrome (v69 on ubuntu 16.04) screws up kerning and as a result the screenshots end up being quite different, more than the 1% threshold I've set.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2410  apparently this is related

Answer (score 7):

options.addArguments("font-render-hinting=none");

This seemed to help. Still messing up plenty of other things but at least kerning is not an issue anymore...